# Disable quotes in sql views, procedures, functions saved with sybase central

Tags: sybase, sqlanywhere

we have updated our database from sqlanywhere 11 to 16. Unfortunately after the update all views, procedures, functions in sybase central have quoted column names.

f.e.
SELECT "customer_id", "customer_name", "customer_nr" as "cNr" from "customer"

Is there an option to disable these quotes? I tried with "SET quoted_identifier Off;" but this didn't work.